# How to trigger and show input when spesific element is choosen with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a select dropdown and i want to show another input field when the "Car" is selected in the list, whithout submiting the form.

Does anyone have a decent way of doing this using jQuery?

```
<?php $array  = array('Bus','Car','Train');?>
<label for="value">Hvordan reiste du?</label>
<select name="value[]" class="form-control">                                            
    <?php foreach($array as $a) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $a; ?>"><?php echo $a;?></option>
    <?php } ?>                                  
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery allows you to listen for a .[change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) on different form elements. You can use it to trigger your condition that checks if the selected value equals to 'car'.

```
$('select.form-control').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'car') {
    # show input
  } else {
    # hide input
  }
});
```

Wrapping your jQuery inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` like Avitus did, will make sure the DOM is loaded before trying to register your selectbox.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('select').on("change", function(){
      if ( this.value == "Car" ) {
          $("#myInput").show();
       }
      else {
          $("#myInput").hide();
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: This will work, but you are missing a curly brace to close your event handler.

Comment: That's what i get for typing too quickly :)